# Autobiography by Sonja Graf

Tags: books

In the book "Chess Bitch" by Jennifer Shahade I have read that Sonja Graf has written an autobiography in Spanish. Can anyone help me locate the book? It could be in Spanish, German, English or Russian.

Comment: You're fluent in all those languages ? Impressive! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

She wrote two autobiographical books while in Argentina: "Así juega una mujer", Buenos Aires 1941 and "Yo soy Susann", Buenos Aires 1946. Susanna was her real first name.
Bibliographic data in WorldCat:

https://www.worldcat.org/title/asi-juega-una-mujer-impresiones-y-recuerdos-de-la-carrera-ajedrecistica-de-la-autora-y-psicologia-de-los-ajedrecistas/oclc/55440304

and

https://www.worldcat.org/title/yo-soy-susann-relato-intimo-y-autobiografico-impresiones-reales-recuerdos-y-confidencias-amorosas-historia-de-la-vida-en-si-misma-con-su-ensenanza-y-su-verdad/oclc/65716357

And this page contains photos of both books (scroll down): http://www.tabladeflandes.com/gabriel/gabriel-capo-16.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer which I upvoted and accepted. Do you know if there are any translations of these books? I can't read in Spanish but I could buy the Spanish originals if that was the only way. Are these books for sale anywhere?

Comment: Never heard of any translations. And I suppose that both books were printed in very small numbers only (remark the little inventory evidence in WorldCat), so it might be difficult to buy a copy.